# AVAudioPlayer Does Not Respect Mute

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

There are other topics on this but I can't comment in them, and I've tried all the approaches listed.

My app has a song that plays when it opens, but hitting the mute on the iPad has no effect (it should mute the song).

Here's my code where I start the sound:

```
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"intro_theme" withExtension:@"wav"] error:NULL];`
[audioPlayer play];
```

And here's the various approaches I've tried:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];

UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
```

Other people seem to be able to get AVAudioPlayer to respect the mute option - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the category AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient?

per [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient):
When you use this category, audio from other apps is silenced. Your audio is silenced by screen locking and by the Silent switch (called the Ring/Silent switch on iPhone).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - it didn't work unfortunately.  Tested setting this before creating the player, after creating the player but before calling play, after calling play, and 1 second after calling play using a timer.

Comment: Are you calling `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];`  after you set the category?

Comment: I was not - but just tried it in the same 3 places.  It returns successful but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

I delayed playing my audio using an NSTimer until 1 second after the call to setCategory.  This is working on iPad 3 & iPad 1 (haven't tested on 2).